Math behind converting SCSS 'darken' to equivalent 'color-mix' function
Say one has the following CSS:
color: darken(#ABCDEF, 10%);

I tried color: color-mix(in srgb, #ABCDEF, #000 10%), and unintuitively enough, it doesn't match!  Sure enough, looking up the Source Code for darken, there's some HSL conversion happening.
Can someone explain the math needed to convert this to a color-mix expression given the precondition that one does not have an HSLA value, but only an RGBA value?
darken(#ABCDEF, 10%) === color-mix(in srgb, ???, ???)


Why would this be "unintuitive"? These functions do two different things. darken is changing the lightness of a color provided, not mixing two colors. The question is, why do you want to use color-mix vs darken? What's the end goal that one of the other isn't solving.

Eliminating sass in favor of custom properties is the ultimate direction.

Not to mention, darken seems to be on its way out of sass in general and isn't included by default in the new module system.  The question really isn't why I would want to use one over the other, the question is regarding the math behind darken and how it translates (or doesn't translate) to the color-mix native css function.

It looks like the answer is to use relative color syntax -- answered in another question, linked to and voted to close this one.

Does this answer your question? How to create color shades using CSS variables similar to darken() of Sass?

Yep - I'm planning on implementing this and wrapping the old sass in a @supports not (hsl(from #fff h s l)) type of construct so it can become gracefully deprecated and ultimately removed in the next major.
